# psycopg2 ThreadedConnectionPool implementation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently using a `ThreadedConnectionPool` from `psycopg2` to lease transactions to a PostgreSQL database and would like a review of my current implementation.

#### Code

```py
from __future__ import annotations

import logging
import threading
import traceback
from contextlib import contextmanager
from dataclasses import dataclass

from psycopg2.pool import ThreadedConnectionPool

from .settings import CONNECTION_OPEN_WARN_THRESHOLD
from .utils import Timer


logger = logging.getLogger()


class Counter(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.value = 0
        self.max = 0
        self._lock = threading.Lock()

    def increment(self):
        with self._lock:
            self.value += 1
            if self.value > self.max:
                self.max = self.value

    def decrement(self):
        with self._lock:
            self.value -= 1

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{id(self):#02x} - {self.name}: current={self.value}, max={self.max}"


@dataclass
class PostgreSQLSimplePool:

    pool: ThreadedConnectionPool
    counter = Counter("Active DB connections")

    @contextmanager
    def transact_session(self, commit: bool = False):
        with Timer() as t:
            conn = self.pool.getconn()
            self.counter.increment()
            logger.debug(self.counter)

            try:
                yield conn
                if commit:
                    conn.commit()
            except Exception:
                conn.rollback()
                raise
            finally:
                self.counter.decrement()
                self.pool.putconn(conn)

        if t.interval > CONNECTION_OPEN_WARN_THRESHOLD:
            logger.warning(f"DB Connection was held open for {t.interval} seconds:")
            traceback.print_stack()
```

#### Config

```py
threaded_pool = ThreadedConnectionPool(
    minconn=1,
    maxconn=20,
    dsn="",  # This relies on standard env vars
)
repo = PostgreSQLSimplePool(pool=threaded_pool)
```

#### Usage

```py
with repo.transact_session() as connection:
    with conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor) as cur:
        # do some stuff with the cursor...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `Counter` should not inherit from `object` in Python 3
- Add PEP484 type-hinting to `name`, as well as all of your return values
- I'm not sure what you were hoping to accomplish with a field width of 2 in `{id(self):#02x}`. IDs will almost certainly be over two characters long when formatted.
- `counter = Counter("Active DB connections")` does not do what you think it does. It doesn't make an instance member on the dataclass, it makes a static member. You'll want to use [field](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.field) passing a default, or perhaps don't write it as a dataclass member at all and instead add it during [`__post_init__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#post-init-processing).
- You have a counter mechanism that has no knowledge of the pool's size. In my imagination the counter's `max` and the [pool](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/pool.html)'s `maxconn` should be the same thing. Currently you have a "statistical" max that only reports on the historical peak connection usage. You could have - instead, or in addition - an "enforced" max. In other words: rather than rolling your own counter with a lock, perhaps you want a [semaphore](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/threading.html#threading.Semaphore) that blocks if the max count is hit.